# Custom address attribute is causing error in admin customer address section

Tags: custom-attributes, magento2.4, address-attribute

I am adding two custom address attribute as `mobile` and `country_code`.

`InstallData.php` as below,

```
<?php

namespace Ocra\CustomerMobile\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'country_code',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Country Code',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 1000,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'country_code')
        ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit',
                    'checkout_register',
                ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'mobile',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Mobile',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 1001,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile')
        ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit',
                    'checkout_register',
                ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();


        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_mobile_verified',
            [
                'type'         => 'int',
                'label'        => 'Is Mobile Verified?',
                'input'        => 'select',
                'source' => 'Ocra\CustomerMobile\Model\Config\Source\Option',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 1002,
                'system'       => 0,
                'default' => 2
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'is_mobile_verified')
        ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit',
                    'checkout_register',
                ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'country_code', [
               'label' => 'Country Code',
               'input' => 'varchar',
               'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
               'source' => '',
               'required' => false,
               'position' => 90,
               'visible' => true,
               'system' => false,
               'is_used_in_grid' => false,
               'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
               'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
               'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
               'frontend_input' => 'hidden',
               'backend' => ''
           ]);

        $attribute=$customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                ->getAttribute('customer_address','country_code')                                  
                ->addData([
                        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                        'used_in_forms' => [
                           'adminhtml_customer_address',
                           'adminhtml_customer',
                           'customer_address_edit',
                           'customer_register_address',
                           'customer_address',
                        ]
                ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'mobile', [
               'label' => 'Mobile',
               'input' => 'varchar',
               'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
               'source' => '',
               'required' => false,
               'position' => 90,
               'visible' => true,
               'system' => false,
               'is_used_in_grid' => false,
               'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
               'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
               'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
               'frontend_input' => 'hidden',
               'backend' => ''
           ]);

        $attribute=$customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                ->getAttribute('customer_address','mobile')                                  
                ->addData([
                        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                        'used_in_forms' => [
                           'adminhtml_customer_address',
                           'adminhtml_customer',
                           'customer_address_edit',
                           'customer_register_address',
                           'customer_address',
                        ]
                ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

After this, if I open `New Address` from admin customer edit screen or new customer screen, address form is not loading instead error is created in `debug.log` and `system.log` as below,

> [2021-01-13 11:55:16] main.CRITICAL: TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
> must be of the type array, null given, called in
> D:\wamp_new\www\magento_2_4\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php
> on line 235 and defined in
> D:\wamp_new\www\magento_2_4\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php:183
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\wamp_new\www\magento_2_4\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php(235):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('country_code',
> NULL)
> #1 D:\wamp_new\www\magento_2_4\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Form\Field.php(85):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('country_code',
> 'varchar', Array)
> #2 D:\wamp_new\www\magento_2_4\vendor\magento\framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent.php(164):

Error on the screen as below,

[image]

Where is it going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 customers have different table's for Customer and Customer Shipping/billing Address.
Adding the Eav attributes to the customer does not affect the addresses.

What you really want, as much as i know, is to add your attributes to the table: Customer_address_entity

You can try using this code:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerAddressEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
    $attributeSetId = $customerAddressEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'is_mobile_verified', [
        'type'         => 'int',
        'label'        => 'Is Mobile Verified?',
        'input'        => 'select',
        'source' => 'Ocra\CustomerMobile\Model\Config\Source\Option',
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'required'     => false,
        'visible'      => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'position'     => 1002,
        'system'       => 0,
        'default' => 2
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'is_mobile_verified')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId
        ]);

    $attribute->save();
}
```